# matplotlib pick_event doesn't work for barh?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is a pyplot.barh example. When user click on red or green bar,script should get the x & y value of bar,so I add pick_event on fig.
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Random data
bottom10 = pd.DataFrame({'amount':-np.sort(np.random.rand(10))})
top10 = pd.DataFrame({'amount':np.sort(np.random.rand(10))[::-1]})

# Create figure and axes for top10
fig,axt = plt.subplots(1)

# Plot top10 on axt
top10.plot.barh(color='red',edgecolor='k',align='edge',ax=axt,legend=False)

# Create twin axes
axb = axt.twiny()

# Plot bottom10 on axb
bottom10.plot.barh(color='green',edgecolor='k',align='edge',ax=axb,legend=False)

# Set some sensible axes limits
axt.set_xlim(0,1.5)
axb.set_xlim(-1.5,0)

# Add some axes labels
axt.set_ylabel('Best items')
axb.set_ylabel('Worst items')

# Need to manually move axb label to right hand side
axb.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
#add event handle 
def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    print 'onpick points:', zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind])

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

But nothing happend when I click the color bar. Why It has no reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you must define `artists` that can be identified and `picked` by a `mouseclick`; then you must make these objects `pickable`.

**Here is a minimum example** with two `hbar` plots that allow you to select the objects with a `mouseclick`; I removed all the formatting in order to focus on the question you asked.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

top10 = pd.DataFrame({'amount' : - np.sort(np.random.rand(10))})
bottom10 = pd.DataFrame({'amount' : np.sort(np.random.rand(10))[::-1]})

# Create figure and axes for top10
fig = plt.figure()
axt = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
axb = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

# Plot top10 on axt
bar_red = top10.plot.barh(color='red', edgecolor='k', align='edge', ax=axt, legend=False, picker=True)
# Plot bottom10 on axb
bar_green = bottom10.plot.barh(color='green', edgecolor='k', align='edge', ax=axb, legend=False, picker=True)

#add event handler 
def onpick(event):
    if isinstance(event.artist, Rectangle):
        print("got the artist", event.artist)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

**after a few clicks, the output may look like this:**

```
got the artist Rectangle(-0.951754,9;0.951754x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(-0.951754,9;0.951754x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(-0.951754,9;0.951754x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(0,5;0.531178x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(0,5;0.531178x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(0,5;0.531178x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(0,2;0.733535x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(0,2;0.733535x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(0,2;0.733535x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(-0.423519,2;0.423519x0.5)
got the artist Rectangle(-0.423519,2;0.423519x0.5)
```

As you did not specify what you wanted to do with the picked object, I only printed its standard `__str__`; if you look up the `matplotlib` documentation, you will find a list of the `properties` you can access and manipulate to extract data.

I'll leave it to you to reformat the plot to your preference.

Comment: Greate! So the magic is adding a argv ' picker=True' when plotting.But in my case ,It's not perfect .because of using twin axes(axb = axt.twiny()),there is only one side has reaction(the green side).maybe that's what twin axis work.